# Does Salesforce automatically creates a cert on successful communication with an external system?

Tags: integration, certificates

We were trying point to point integration between Salesforce & SAP. As a standard method we tested the service exposed by SAP on SoapUI and then from Salesforce successfully. I see now that a self-signed certificate has been generated in Salesforce automatically.The date of creation of this certificate is the same as the date on which Salesforce made a successful connection with SAP. 
[image]

The unique name has been named as 'testsap'. Does Salesforce automatically creates a cert on successful communication with an external system ?

Comment: Highly doubtful that the system generated this automatically. If you look in Setup > Security Controls > **View Setup Audit Trail** who does it show as the user who created the Certificate?

Comment: @MarkPond Hi Mark, I see in the audit trail that a developer has created the log. Thanks for your help. I just tend to believe him. Now he says that maybe he created while sleeping. :)